# Error : Invalid conversion from char to const char *

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, data-conversion

I am facing this problem from day 1.

Actually, the book I am reading from has this program written in this way, but when I check it practically on Eclipse IDE, it does not work properly, always showing this error:

> invalid conversion from char to const char *

Although I know what the issue is, I don't know how to resolve this problem, and I am facing this problem with every program in which there is some string operation.

The error is with this `if` statement:

`if(!strcmp(str, *ptr[i]))`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *ptr[10] = { "books", "television", "computer", "sports" };
    int i = 0;
    char str[25];
    cout << "\nEnter your favorite leisure pursuit here :" << "\n";
    cin >> str;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(str, *ptr[i]))
        {
            cout << "\n your favorite pursuit is available here " << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == 4)
    {
        cout << "\n\nYour favorite leisure is not available here" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: Good, regular indentation makes many families of mistakes nearly impossible to commit.

Comment: @user4581301  i did not get you??

Comment: Your code indentation was very very bad which made it hard to read. To make a code block type ``` press enter paste the code directly from your editor with no changes press enter type ``` and press enter again.

Comment: Many bugs are visible as irregularities in the code. If your code has few irregularities, these kinds of mistakes stand out.

Comment: @drescherjm is it ok now??

Comment: `*ptr[i]` -- What is the result of doing this?  Now, what is the result of doing this: `ptr[i]`?  You could have also figured this out by doing `std::cout << *ptr[i] << "\n" << ptr[i];` to see the difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie string comparison is happening in the loop??

Comment: @JasmeetSingh -- The error `invalid conversion from char to const char *` basically tells you what you are doing wrong.  `*ptr[i]` is a single character.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie user4581301 it worked. i removed the dereferncing

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so you mean when we write char *ptr[10] = {"books","television,"computer","sports"};           Here ptr is pointing to first character 'b' of books???

Comment: Also this book doesn't look like good to learn C++ from scratch. Since it mostly uses C functions and constructs. That may be good when learning C++ with C knowledge, but useless otherwise.

Comment: @Jasmeet Singh I can surely say that the book is bad.:)

Comment: @sklott i have C knowledge but still can you suggest me a good C++ book bcz i have really found many errors in the example programs it has

Comment: @VladfromMoscow agree, any suggestions?

Comment: Take look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: `so you mean when we write char *ptr[10]` -- That is a declaration.  That is different than when you are executing the code.  You are declaring that there are 10 `char *`.  What do you do when you want to access each of them?  You are mixing up the declaration with when you want to access them.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp()` compares two null-terminated `const char*` strings.  But, you are trying to compare a null-terminated `char[]` string to a single `char`, hence the error.  This is because you are dereferencing the 2nd `const char*` string to access its 1st `char` element.

`ptr` is an array of `const char*` pointers, so you need to drop the extra `*` dereference operator when accessing `ptr[i]`, so that you compare the whole string, not just a single character of the string, eg:

```
if (strcmp(str, ptr[i]) == 0)
```

Comment: Pay special attention to the `== 0`. It resolves a second mistake. `strcmp` returns  0 on a match, the distance between the two strings is zero.

Comment: I hate functions that return `0` on success, but I hate it even more when people use `!` instead of `== 0` when testing those functions for success. Even though it is functionally okay, it just doesn't read correctly in my mind.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, because it pretends that the value is a boolean, *but* inverts the meanings of `true` and `false`. Both are bad on their own, in combination they are an abomination.

Comment: big thanks to @RemyLebeau for such a detailed comment and everyone here who jumped up on this problem so quickly.